# Window Azure Tools for Eclipse - failed

Tags: eclipse, azure

Im trying to install Windows Azure tools for Eclipse by following [Tutorial](http://www.windowsazure4e.org/download/). After i fill the location and name, it doesn't install but throw an error.
Error

```
Network connection problems encountered during search.
Unable to access "http://http://www.windowsazure4e.org/update".
Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
Premature end of file.
Error parsing site stream. [Premature end of file.]
Premature end of file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded new version of Eclipse and it working fine now.
Using :

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.    
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
```

Comment: which tutorial you used for install Window Azure...?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link you have given. It says

> http://http://www.windowsazure4e.org/update whereas it should be 
>   http://www.windowsazure4e.org/update